# My custom UIView in Swift does not show all buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I can't create custom UIView properly inside my view controller. What I want is four buttons (UNDO, DISLIKE, LIKE, INFO) in vertical side. But my UNDO and INFO button not appeared properly inside my view controller.

```
let ChoosePersonButtonHorizontalPadding:CGFloat = 40.0
let ChoosePersonButtonVerticalPadding:CGFloat = 20.0

func constructUndoButton() -> Void{
        let button:UIButton =  UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"undo")!
        button.frame = CGRectMake(ChoosePersonButtonHorizontalPadding, CGRectGetMaxY(self.backCardView.frame) + ChoosePersonButtonVerticalPadding, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        button.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func constructNopeButton() -> Void{
        let button:UIButton =  UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"nope")!
        button.frame = CGRectMake(ChoosePersonButtonHorizontalPadding, CGRectGetMaxY(self.backCardView.frame) + ChoosePersonButtonVerticalPadding, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        button.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func constructLikedButton() -> Void{
        let button:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"liked")!
        button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame) - image.size.width - ChoosePersonButtonHorizontalPadding, CGRectGetMaxY(self.backCardView.frame) + ChoosePersonButtonVerticalPadding, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        button.setImage(image, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }

    func constructInfoButton() -> Void{
        let button:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"info")!
        button.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame) - image.size.width - ChoosePersonButtonHorizontalPadding, CGRectGetMaxY(self.backCardView.frame) + ChoosePersonButtonVerticalPadding, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        button.setImage(image, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }
```

Result (ignore the image and button colour part)

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your undo button and nope button are in the same frame so that overlapped.

```
func constructNopeButton() -> Void{
    let button:UIButton =  UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    let image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"nope")!
    button.frame = CGRectMake(ChoosePersonButtonHorizontalPadding +undoButton.frame.size.width + undoButton.frame.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(self.backCardView.frame) + ChoosePersonButtonVerticalPadding, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    button.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

you might use this code to arrange the second view. But there are ways to make this better.